# Use CDN url instead of image path with mysql bulk import

Tags: database, image, product-images, gallery, cdn

I want to insert and use an image urls from my own CDN directly into the database. I want to do this to save space because I use the images in other applications as well.

I've wrote a function that populates this two tables: 
**catalog_product_entity_media_gallery** 
and 
**catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value**.

This is what I've inserted as value : **http://cdn.domain.com/products/nike/448224-010-00.jpg**, while this is the way magento does: **/4/4/448224-010-00.jpg**

So far so good. But now magento creates an url like this: **http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/*http://cdn.domain.com/products/nike/448224-010-00.jpg***

Is there a way to tell magento (extension or module) not to use the media folder and base url? I also want the width or height to be added to the url when it's called.

Add querystring like this: **?w=100&h=100**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research on how to override a function on a Model, I've created my own module/extension. This extension extends the **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image** Model and this is what I've changed to make it work:

```
class ImageCdn_Model_Catalog_Product_Image extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
{
    protected $_cdnFile;

    public function setBaseFile($file)  {

        // add cdn url
        if ($file && strpos($file, 'http') === 0) {
            $this->_cdnFile = $file;
        }

        return parent::setBaseFile($file);;
    }

    public function getUrl()
    {
        $cdnFile = $this->_cdnFile;

        if ($cdnFile) {

            $width = $this->_width;
            $height = $this->_height;

            if (!is_null($width)){

                if(strpos($cdnFile, "?")){
                    $cdnFile .= "&";
                }else{
                    $cdnFile .= "?";
                }

                $cdnFile.= "w=" . $width;
            }

            if (!is_null($height)){

                if(strpos($cdnFile, "?")){
                    $cdnFile .= "&";
                }else{
                    $cdnFile .= "?";
                }

                $cdnFile.= "h=" . $height;
            }

            return $cdnFile;
        }

        return parent::getUrl();
    }

}
```